# Can I change a calculated column to a Yes/No column?

Tags: column, calculated-column

I currently have a list created with multiple column and column types.  One column is a formula based on the answer of another....I need to change the column to a Yes or No choice instead of relying on the answer of the other column.  However, whenever I go to edit that column, it will not let me change the type....help!

Answer (score 4):

You are unable to change the types of Columns in SharePoint lists - simply because it's impossible to guarantee how to transform the data stored in one column type to another.

What you can do, is create your Yes/No column, go to DataSheet view, and see if you are able to copy/paste the values from your calculated column over to the new Yes/No column.

Comment: Actually you can change column types, some of them are convertable. But not all, as in this case.